# Rewrite URL in Apache when variable =1

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL set like this:

```
test.com?results=1&question=1234
```

I am trying to make it so if `results=1`, it rewrites to this:

```
test.com/results/question/1234
```

I have managed to get the question part, but with the results part, it just breaks, meaning I can not `$_GET['question']`.

So far, for this individual line I use:

```
RewriteRule ^results/question/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?results=$1&question=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I think it has something to do with me needing to tell `/results/` that `results=1` is set, but I am unsure how to do this. I figured a way I could do it is by making the rewrite url `/results/1/question/1234`, but I don't particularly want that, as it looks cleaner without the `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are capturing only one value but using `$2` in your target. You can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^results/question/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?results=1&question=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: All done! Appreciate that, first time using Stackoverflow and it was incredible :) I understand how the values work now too which is awesome! Have a great day